# How do I call spamming in multiple questions to moderator attention?

Tags: discussion, support

While reviewing, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964594/gpuimage-green-screen/35740290#35740290)
and a few reviews on I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258575/file-format-for-saving-video-with-alpha-channel-in-ios/35740332#35740332). This user seems to post the same (useless) answer all over the place.

How do I call this to moderator attention, e.g. is there a flag-option on users I failed to find?

Comment: Side note: The offending user has had all of his posts spam-deleted and is answer banned now, so bringing it up on meta worked. Still follow CodyGray's advice for future occurences, though.

Comment: @Magisch, I did that nonetheless, but thanks for the follow-up :)

Comment: We also have a chat room, the SO Close Vote Reviewers room, where we harbour our resident Spam detector Smokey (Smoke Detector) which automatically detects spam. It also has a manual post report option for regulars, at which point it will get added to a Blacklist. Every further post from blacklisted users gets brought up there and usually swiftly dealt with then.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just flag one of their answers, picking the custom "in need of moderator intervention" option. Use the textbox to explain the problem as you've done here, either linking to their other answers or just linking directly to their profile. The moderator who processes your flag will follow up, either by deleting the individual answers or destroying the entire account.

There is no need to raise *multiple* flags. For example, please don't flag each answer separately. A single flag on one of the answers (it doesn't matter which one you pick) will do.

There is no way to flag a particular user because we want to keep the focus on *content*, rather than users. There are occasionally edge cases like this where a user is the problem, but it still works just as well to flag the offending answer.

Comment: I'd like to add that, perhaps barring extreme cases, this should not be brought up on Meta.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: Why?

Comment: @justhalf [The Meta Effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect). ShadowWizard's comment on the answer there describes just what happened here.

Comment: @Mogsdad Link to [ShadowWizard's Comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect#comment773446_235226) (though in this case I'd argue that it's not really a result of the Meta Effect as much as it's just standard moderator actions prompted by a Meta post)

Answer (score 0):

If a user posts *duplicate* answers (exact duplicates), those are *automatically* added to a moderator queue to be reviewed.  Typically, if they're not horrible spam, that's sufficient, and we've received suggestions to leave those alone and not flag them (as it may end up confusing the issue if you flag the one that the system doesn't flag).

Otherwise, raise flags as Cody suggests (if the post is not an exact duplicate, or if the post is in more-urgent-than-usual need of attention.